# Swiper.js variable + dynamic width slides, based on image width

Tags: swiper.js

I'm building a Swiper of book covers, with the book title below. I'm using
`slidesPerView: 'auto'` in order to allow flexible width slides, but the problem I have is that sometimes the title is wider than the image, which looks strange. I don't want to specify a set width per slide, since book covers vary in size, but I do want the text below the image to wrap, constrained to the width of the image. I cannot figure out how to do both.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?